# Unable to add a group member using microsoft graph api in a bash script

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

If I run below http script from the graph.microsoft.com docs, it works fine.

```http
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/9746dce-f530182/members/$ref
Content-type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJub25jZSI6Il9Y-pCiTwLhttVX5wg 

{
  "@odata.id": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/e7cb-2f96bba6"
}
```

where:

1. 9746dce-f530182 = group-id,
2. e7cb-2f96bba6 = user-id and
3. eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJub25jZSI6Il9Y-pCiTwLhttVX5wg = auth-token

I would like to run this as a bash script, so that I can automate the token generation and the POST call. My script looks like so.

```bash
CLIENT_ID='283f4d25-87bde0ef'
TENANT_ID='2d987312-a4ff5ea0'
CLIENT_SECRET='XSY8Q~4Ls-ahi'
GROUP_ID="9746dc-00182"
USER_ID='e7cb46-bbbba6'

AT_URL="https://login.microsoftonline.com/${TENANT_ID}/oauth2/token"

auth_response=$(curl -X POST -d 'grant_type=client_credentials&client_id='${CLIENT_ID}'&client_secret='$CLIENT_SECRET'&resource=https://graph.microsoft.com' $AT_URL | jq .)
token="$(echo $auth_response | jq -r .token_type) $(echo $auth_response | jq -r .access_token)"

curl -H "Authorization: $token" -H "Content-type: application/json" -d '{"@odata.id": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/'$USER_ID'"}' "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/$GROUP_ID/members/$ref"
```

But this fails with the below error. What am I missing?

```json
{"error":{"code":"Request_BadRequest","message":"Unsupported resource type 'DirectoryObject' for operation 'Create'.","innerError":{"date":"2022-05-25T11:24:21","request-id":"e189dc-063e","client-request-id":"e189d-2e42063e"}}}
```

Comment: Thanks for reaching out to us , this looks like a syntax error , could you please cross check your UserId, please check with the same UserId you tried in graph explorer.

Comment: Hi @vickykumar, thanks for your response. It is the same user id. It works in a http file and not from a bash script

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fis the issue by changing the last line of the script to the following. The problem was that the `$ref` at the end of the URL was treated as a bash variable.

```bash
curl -H "Authorization: $token" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"@odata.id": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/'${USER_ID}'"}' 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/'$GROUP_ID'/members/$ref'
```

Hope this helps someone else.

The final script looks like below

```bash
CLIENT_ID='283f4d25-87bde0ef'
TENANT_ID='2d987312-a4ff5ea0'
CLIENT_SECRET='XSY8Q~4Ls-ahi'
GROUP_ID="9746dc-00182"
USER_ID='e7cb46-bbbba6'

AT_URL="https://login.microsoftonline.com/${TENANT_ID}/oauth2/token"

auth_response=$(curl -X POST -d 'grant_type=client_credentials&client_id='${CLIENT_ID}'&client_secret='$CLIENT_SECRET'&resource=https://graph.microsoft.com' $AT_URL | jq .)
token="$(echo $auth_response | jq -r .token_type) $(echo $auth_response | jq -r .access_token)"

curl -H "Authorization: $token" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"@odata.id": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/'${USER_ID}'"}' 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/'$GROUP_ID'/members/$ref'
```